# How to transform XML data into SQL Server table (part 2)

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml

I have asked a question similar to this one. But this time I need to transpose the data.

I have a XML data like this :

```
<root>
 <log realm="ABC" at="Wed Oct 15 00:00:02 2014.211" lifespan="2279ms">
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="IN">
      <header>6000911384</header>
      <field id="0" value="0800"/>
      <field id="3" value="980000"/>
      <field id="11" value="000852"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
</root>
```

is it possible to transform that XML data into table like this :

```
AT             |lifespan|direction |ID_0 |ID_3  |ID_11
-------------------------------------------------------
Wed Oct 15 2014|2279ms  |in        |0800 |980000|000852
```

Please help, thank you all

Comment: If you want columns whose *names* depend on the data in the XML then you're going to end up with some *ugly* dynamic SQL. Queries, generally, return a fixed set of columns - in terms of the number of columns returned, there names and their data types.

Comment: what if I already have a table with fixed column, AT, LifeSpan, Direction, ID_0, ID_3, ID_11. Is it possible?

Comment: So it only has to work with XML that has *exactly* those 3 ID values?

Comment: yup. exactly those 3 ID Values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This unpacks your *specific* data into the result set you've asked for, but how reusable this is depends a lot on what other pieces of XML you might want to unpack:

```
declare @inp xml = '<root>
 <log realm="ABC" at="Wed Oct 15 00:00:02 2014.211" lifespan="2279ms">
  <receive>
    <isomsg direction="IN">
      <header>6000911384</header>
      <field id="0" value="0800"/>
      <field id="3" value="980000"/>
      <field id="11" value="000852"/>
    </isomsg>
  </receive>
</log>
</root>'

select
    n.value('@at','varchar(10)') + SUBSTRING(n.value('@at','varchar(30)'),20,5) as AT,
    n.value('@lifespan','varchar(20)') as lifespan,
    n.value('receive[1]/isomsg[1]/@direction','varchar(10)') as direction,
    n.value('receive[1]/isomsg[1]/field[@id="0"][1]/@value','varchar(10)') as id_0,
    n.value('receive[1]/isomsg[1]/field[@id="3"][1]/@value','varchar(10)') as id_3,
    n.value('receive[1]/isomsg[1]/field[@id="11"][1]/@value','varchar(10)') as id_11
from @inp.nodes('/root/log') n(n)
```

Result:

```
AT              lifespan             direction  id_0       id_3       id_11
--------------- -------------------- ---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
Wed Oct 15 2014 2279ms               IN         0800       980000     000852
```

Comment: wow.. that works beautifully. thank you very much Damien_The_Unbeliever.